# How does the while loop in this code snippet work?

Tags: c++

This is the code snippet that I found in a book:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    // currVal is the number we're counting; we'll read new values into val
int currVal = 0, val = 0;
// read first number and ensure that we have data to process
if (std::cin >> currVal) {
    int cnt = 1;  // store the count for the current value we're processing
    while (std::cin >> val) { // read the remaining numbers
        if (val == currVal)   // if the values are the same
            ++cnt;            // add 1 to cnt
        else { // otherwise, print the count for the previous value
            std::cout << currVal << " occurs "
                      << cnt << " times" << std::endl;
            currVal = val;    // remember the new value
            cnt = 1;          // reset the counter
        }
    }  // while loop ends here
    // remember to print the count for the last value in the file
    std::cout << currVal <<  " occurs "
              << cnt << " times" << std::endl;
} // outermost if statement ends here
return 0;
}
```

This code snippet calculates how many times a number is entered into the input stream and uses the while loop to receive and unknown amount of numbers.

The question, however, is when I enter different numbers and not one repeating into the stream. (and entered Ctrl+D, which indicates end-of-file). The input stream seem to require taking an extra input before showing me the number of times the last value occurs.

For example if I entered

> 1 2 3 4

Separated by a space, and finally the Ctrl+D indicating the end-of-file, the output will be:

```
1 occurs 1 times
2 occurs 1 times
3 occurs 1 times 
<requests for input>
4 occurs 1 times
```

but if I enter something that is not an integer into the stream

> 1 2 3 4a

the output runs smoothly, as expected.

Why is this?

Comment: What do you think should happen when you type "12 34"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`while (std::cin >> val)` will loop until `cin` enters a state where it is no longer valid.  Using Ctrl+D sends the EOF character which causes the `eof` flag of `cin` to get set and causing it to evaluate as `false` ending the loop.

The input of `1 2 3 4a` basically does the same thing.  When you input a letter when `cin` expects a number it causes the input to fail setting the `fail` flag of `cin`.  This also causes `cin` to evaluate to `false` and ending the loop.

---

One way to get around all of this is to use a `std::string` and grab all of the input at one time.  Then you can load that `std::string` into a `std::stringstream` and get the individual elements from that.

```
std::string line;
std::getline(cin, line)
std::stringstream ss(line);
while (ss >> val)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: thing is also, that ctrl-D guaranteed to work properly only at beginning of line, so if it really depends on console how program would react on it , if it was entered right after thise numbers. In general one should enter them separately... 4 and ctrl-D may get out of sync. It essentially means in this case : flush input buffer. If input buffer is empty, then it is treated as EOF.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie -- just to be clear about boundaries, the C++ language does not guarantee **anything** about ctrl-D, regardless of where it is in the input. It's entirely up to the console to interpret that, and your comment about the beginning of a line is about a particular console implementation.

Comment: @PeteBecker I never meant it be part of 14882. It related to environment (POSIX, etc) than C++. tbh I not sure which agreement or document governs POSIX console. On non-POSIX ctrl-D may not work at all.

Comment: Thank you all. It seems that I did not provide enough examples.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lApoAJb1Cw5d03dI3I1VIo5WxoQPwO_-39bKWSOtvpA/edit?usp=sharing

I don't know how best to describe my current question. But why is that? It seems to require taking inputs before showing me the final value...